# Data organization in Cuda kernels

Tags: cuda

I'm new to Cuda and been reading tutorials and other open source code, to try to understand things. I know the general concept of thread hierarchies.

TL;DR, all the tutorials I read have assumed that the data sent to the kernel is also organized in this hierarchy, without explicitly having done so before launching the kernel. Shouldn't the data passed to the kernel be re-arranged in the grid>block>thread hierarchy before being passed to the kernel? Below are two snippets that confused me in this regard.

I followed this `x_plus_y` tutorial [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/). In this tutorial, the following snippet:

```
_global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
    y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}
```

In the above snippet, we want to add corresponding elements in `x` and `y`, but how do I know, that `x` and `y` are so placed in the GPU, that the index `i` (which is computed using blockIdx,blockDim etc), actually points to corresponding elements of `x` and `y`. If `x` and `y` are placed one after the other in memory, shouldn't the index used for `y` take into account length of `x`? I'm missing some key intuitive understanding here. Also, how do I know where in the GPU has some random element of array been mapped, say x[1011]? Or do I not need to care about explicit positioning of my data, due to some kind of abstraction?

I'll also discuss another snippet, from an open-source torch repo. This is a kernel for computing a distance metric between two sets of point-clouds. Each cloud is an `Nx3` matrix (has `N` 3-D points).

`b` is the batch-size (so, `b` number of clouds are passed to the kernel)

`n` is the number of points in each cloud of the first set

`m` is the number of points in each cloud of the second set.

Example, the first set of clouds can be (16,1024,3) and second set (16,512,3):

```
__global__ void NmDistanceKernel(int b,int n,const float * xyz,int m,const float * xyz2,float * result,int * result_i){
    const int batch=512;
    __shared__ float buf[batch*3];
    for (int i=blockIdx.x;i<b;i+=gridDim.x){
        for (int k2=0;k2<m;k2+=batch){
            int end_k=min(m,k2+batch)-k2;
            for (int j=threadIdx.x;j<end_k*3;j+=blockDim.x){
                buf[j]=xyz2[(i*m+k2)*3+j];
            }


        for (int j=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.y*blockDim.x;j<n;j+=blockDim.x*gridDim.y){
                float x1=xyz[(i*n+j)*3+0];
                float y1=xyz[(i*n+j)*3+1];
                float z1=xyz[(i*n+j)*3+2];
            }
    }
}
```

The above kernel, is launched as follows:

```
NmDistanceKernel<<<dim3(32,16,1),512>>>(batch_size, n, xyz1.data<float>(), m, xyz2.data<float>(), dist1.data<float>(), idx1.data<int>());
```

Again, in the above kernel, the author has assumed that the data they have passed to the kernel are organized such that the indexing mechanism will work. They didn't explicitly place each point in each thread and then a bunch of points inside a block and a bunch of clouds inside a grid. This structure is however assumed inside the kernel.

Comment: In your first example, x and y should be allocated as two separate, contiguous regions of memory, and they should have equal length. Regardless of the actual memory addresses, x[0] and y[0] each refer to the first element of those arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling a kernel, you must have placed the data into the GPU.

Data is mostly passed in in Arrays of Data, so the structure of these arrays are the same on the GPU as they were in your host code.

In you first example, the arrays `x` and `y` are passed in seperately, so the indices for `x` and `y` both start at `0`. You could pass them in in one big array, and then the indexing would need to be adjusted.

That has been done in your other example. The array `xyz` consists of the x y and z values of all points. The order goes like `x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3 ...`. That is why when accessing the values you see `x = [...]+0; y = [...]+1; z = [...]+2;`. For the next point, the indices all increase by 3.

To then access you data in kernels, you need to refer to the Identifiers that CUDA gives you. You use the position of the thread inside your grid and blocks.

In the first example, the programmer chose to start of the threads all reading the first consecutive entries in the arrays. He does so by assigning a unique `index` to each thread:

> int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

`threadIdx.x` tells us where the thread resides in a block, so it would be enough, if we were only launching one block. But then different threads in different blocks would have the same index. We have to separate them by getting their `blockIdx.x`. The block is `blockDim.x` long and the first thread in the second block should continue after the last thread in block 1. So the above formula for `index` forms.

Then, each thread jumps forwards, so that the very first thread next reads the first data after the data the last thread just read, and so on.

The more dimensions your launched grid uses, the more complex these calculations have to be. Try starting out with simple grids and increase the complexity if you're comfortable with them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that each point-cloud has been flattened like that. I don't exactly get how it was arranged at the higher level. That is, w.r.t grids,blocks and threads. Or does Cuda takes care of that automatically? That is, will Thread0 inside Block0 inside Grid0 always refer to the first data element I pass?

Comment: I added another part to the solution, does that help you?